# How to attach mouse events to Icon style OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

I need to place an image as an arrow and change the rotation depending on the mouse cursor. I have decided to use Icon object.

```
import {Icon} from 'ol/style.js';

const icon =new Icon({
  anchor: [0.5, 46],
  anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
  anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
  src: 'data/icon.png',
});
```

Is it possible to bind a JS mouse event to ab icon? (mousemove, mouseup, mouseleave)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
map.on('pointermove', event => {
  window.map_hover_latest = event
})
```

that will get you the current position of the cursor to work with.

Comment: could also utilize [this](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_control_MousePosition-MousePosition.html)